# Subfiles not working when different folder levels exist between main and component parts

Tags: subfiles, data-structures

I have the following folder structure

```
Project
 | 00Main
 |  |
 |  | Main.tex
 | 01Components
 |  | IntroFolder
 |  |  | Introduction.tex
 |  | DataChapterFolder
 |  |  | Data.tex
 |  | TexVariablesFolder
 |  |  | MacrosAndVariables.tex
```

And so forth.

In the 'Main.tex' file I use subfiles package to include my data and intro.tex files within begin{document}

But I use \inpnut to include my macrosand variable that come before the document stuff.

```
\input{../01Components/TexVariablesFolder/MacrosAndVariables.tex}

\begin{document}
  \subfile{../01Components/IntroFolder/Introduction.tex}
\end{document}
```

And this WORKS.  Its great.

BUT.

If I try to compile ONLY the 'Introduction.tex' file (to save time).  I get errors asking for my 'MacrosAndVariables.tex' file.

I don't know if I can explain, but when compiling the Introduction, it wants to go up two folder levels (../../).  But the 'input' command only goes up one.

If I change \input to be

```
\input{../../01Components/TexVariablesFolder/MacrosAndVariables.tex}
```

when I'm compiling in the introduction folder.  Then it does WORK.

But then when I go back and compile the 'main' document, I have to remove the extra ../ from the \input.

I guess the relative paths are kind of relative to what you are compiling, and not relative to the file where they are found.

Is there a way to fix this?

I don't know how to give a MWE since its very hard drive structure dependent.

Comment: why don't you use \subfile for the file too?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I don't know, it doesn't work for me when I use \subfile in the preamble.  If I replace \input with \subfile it doesn't find the files at all.  \subfile works in the \begin{document} area though. So I know the package is loading.  Just doesn't work in the preamble.

Comment: Sorry I mixed up \subfile and \subimport (from the import package).